# How to following summation without using binomial expansion

Tags: complex-analysis

I wanted to show that for $|z|<1$ has 
$$\frac{z}{1-z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1-z^4}+\cdots+\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}+\cdots=\frac{z}{1-z}$$
$$\frac{z}{1+z}+\frac{2z^2}{1+z^2}+\cdots+\frac{2^kz^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}+\cdots=\frac{z}{1-z}$$

I had solved this problem directly by taking binomial expansion of denominator term and adding term I get RHS term.

I wanted to solve it using other method.

Is it possible?

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried $\, f(z) = g(z) + c f(z^2)\,$?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
S_n=\frac{z}{1-z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1-z^4}+\cdots+\frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}.
$$
By induction we have $$
S_n=\frac{z+z^2+\cdots+z^{2^{n+1}-1}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}.
$$
So we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n=\frac{z}{1-z}.$$
Similarly we can show by induction
\begin{align}
T_k&=\frac{z}{1+z}+\frac{2z^2}{1+z^2}+\cdots+\frac{2^kz^{2^k}}{1+z^{2^k}}\\
&=\frac{z+2z^2+3z^3+\cdots+(2^{k+1}-1)z^{2^{k+1}-1}}{1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{2^{k+1}-1}}\\
&\to z\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}}{\frac{1}{1-z}}=\frac{z}{1-z}
\end{align}